# Dynamically update content in the app from iTunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have the application on AppStore which uses some content. Content is dynamic, so it could be updated from time to time. I do not want to use third-party servers to manage this content.
Is it possible, somehow, update content from Apple's iTunes Connect server without downloading new version of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make content of the application dynamic here are possible ways to do so:

- First one is you can use API to load content into Application. By this way you can easily change it any time & it will be updated into application
- If you don't want to use API than the only way is to make content static & every time when you change content you need to upload new version to apply changes.

I hope it will help you.